# Method getTagValue() is undefined in JAVA

Tags: java, xml

I'm new to Java. I saw many example about reading XML and when I tried to copy to my code I got an error that getTagValue is undefined.
I'm using Eclipse, JRE 1.6.

As well as I understand that method (getTagValue) is exist?

This is the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

The method getTagValue(String, Element) is undefined for the type WriteXMLFile
The method getTagValue(String, Element) is undefined for the type WriteXMLFile
The method getTagValue(String, Element) is undefined for the type WriteXMLFile
The method getTagValue(String, Element) is undefined for the type WriteXMLFile
```

this the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;



public class WriteXMLFile 
  {

public static void main(String argv[])
{

  try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // root elements
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    // staff elements
    Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
    rootElement.appendChild(staff);

    // set attribute to staff element
    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue("1");
    staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

    // shorten way
    // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

    // firstname elements
    Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
    firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
    staff.appendChild(firstname);

    // lastname elements
    Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
    lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
    staff.appendChild(lastname);

    // nickname elements
    Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
    nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mkyong"));
    staff.appendChild(nickname);

    // salary elements
    Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
    salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
    staff.appendChild(salary);

    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("file.xml"));

    // Output to console for testing
    // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    transformer.transform(source, result);

    System.out.println("File saved!");

  } 
  catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) 
  {
    pce.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (TransformerException tfe) 
  {
    tfe.printStackTrace();
  }

  /////  read
  try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("c:\\file.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

           Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
           if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

              Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

              System.out.println("First Name : " + getTagValue("firstname", eElement));
              System.out.println("Last Name : " + getTagValue("lastname", eElement));
              System.out.println("Nick Name : " + getTagValue("nickname", eElement));
              System.out.println("Salary : " + getTagValue("salary", eElement));

           }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

}

Comment: Post your code and the error your are getting.

Comment: Are you talking about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976266/dom-xml-parser-java-same-tags In this example, the method is added.

Comment: So as I undrstand this method is not "built-in" in the SAX packages?

Comment: Build .java class, where getTagValue() defined, renew the jar if required and then cleana and build your project. Then run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method needs to be included in your class file somewhere

```
private String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();

    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
```

Comment: Give credits to @JMelnik... This is essentially what he suggested in his comment.

Comment: I stumbled on this problem while I ran into it. his answer didn't help me. I had to go and find this workaround on my own.